# Should bounties be paid for information exposure?

Tags: cvss, bug-bounty, information-exposure

An ethical hacker found that a system I own, has an exposure of information. They were able to determine the programming language, a web framework and the exact versions of both from a stack trace by causing an unhandled exception in the app by providing an irregular payload. There is no exploitable vulnerability, per-se, but this information provides an attacker with additional information about our systems, by which one could find something that's actually exploitable. Should a bounty be paid for this finding? Does it matter if there are open CVEs for this system or not? According to CVSS, I think it's 0 or None.

Comment: You can pay for information disclosure, and at the same time you could not pay for unauthenticated remote code execution as SYSTEM. It's up to your company.

Comment: A suggestion: have (interanlly-defined) tiers of rewards based on the severity of the disclosed issue.  In the past, for things like that (if we decided we cared enough to fix them), we didn't provide a monetary reward but we did list them on our responsible disclosure thanks page, which is something people like because it looks good on resumes.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not a bounty should be provided is up to the organization, there are no (informal) rules on which these kinds of decisions must be based. Usually, you would indicate in your vulnerability disclosure policy what kind of reports are accepted, and which of these reports may be eligible for a bounty.

That being said, information exposure could be the starting point for a more sophisticated attack, especially if the information indicates that vulnerable software is used. You could use the type and severity of the information exposed in your determination of whether a bounty is fitting in this case.